# Getting direct messages using Twitter REST api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rest, twitter

I'm experimenting with twitter REST API with Ruby on Rails.

I'm using twitter gem for the same. I could get the client object using in my code.

`client = current_domain.twitter_accounts.first.client`

following the documentation given [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Client)

The `client` object works fine. But I couldn't get `DirectMessages` in the same way.

Also followed [this](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) documentation. Here I could not find a way to get `DirectMessages`. Is there a way in REST API to get twitter direct messages. Or do I need to implement Streaming API.

Comment: Did you try `client.direct_messages`?

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich Thanks it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Client

```
Methods included from DirectMessages
#create_direct_message, #destroy_direct_message, #direct_message, #direct_messages, #direct_messages_received, #direct_messages_sent
```

These map to the REST API endpoints

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages/sent

n.b. you won't get group messages through this API and will need to rebuild an inbox model e.g. sequence replies of replies between yourself and the recipient.